# Strange shading 'glitch' on imported glb models

Tags: texturing, artifacts

I'm coming across an issue where the textures on this steam mop model are covered in what I can only describe a glitches or artifacts. The model is exported from Adobe Stager as a .glb file and opens fine in stager and on online 3d viewers but has an issue in blender.

Here is the model in Blender.
[image: Steam mop model open in Blender showing graphical glitches on textures]

And the exact same model opened in Stager.
[image: Steam mop model open in Adobe Stager with no glitches]

What could cause this? Is it an import issue with blender or from the adobe side? I have 2 other steam mops and those models worked fine doing the same export/import workflow. I have just switched to Blender 4.0 but this issue is present in Blender 3.6 as well.

Any help would be appreciated, my knowledge of 3d modelling is very very limited, we get the models from our suppliers and use 3d software mainly for compositing and making basic animations for videos.

Thanks

Edit:
Screenshot showing one of the material nodes.
[image: 3D mop model showing material node]

Comment: This looks like a shader (material) issue. Your model has 29 objects. If you can select one of them, and share a screenshot of the shader nodes of one material, it will be very helpful in figuring out the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've attached a screenshot to my original post. 
Interestingly I changed the shading (I don't know the correct term) to 'shade smooth' and it seems to be showing correctly. Don't know if this is of any help but it's somewhat 'fixed'.
I feel like this is an issue down to the format we receive the models (CAD built) and the fact that we don't do any mesh work on them. Blender is still quite new to our workflow and non of us are 3D experts in any stretch of imagination.

Comment: You're welcome! I agree. Since, you don't have any textures, this is most likely an import issue. If you don't mind, can you post your fix as an answer? Something like, "Setting the shading to shade smooth fixed the issue." This should help people who may run into this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the shading to 'shade smooth' fixed the shading issue I had.